# How to store and retrieve date values

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I want to Insert date in `textbox` with PHP to **mysql** database. But i can't do it and showing with format `dd/mm/yyyy` in table

Comment: can you be some what more clear with what you want

Comment: Show us the code you currently got, much easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `date` function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
You have good examples at the manual page.

For parsing a date, you can use `strtok`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php
or `explode`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php